# search in eloquent return query variable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my problem. Please help

I have these two tables Course and Students. Students take courses. Now I want to get a specific course as shown then see in student table if this course is taken by the student.

```
Course table:

id
name
description

Student table:

user_id
course_id
semester
address
phone
```

What I tried:

```
    $course = Course::where('name', '=', $data["id"]);

    $enroll= Students::where('course_id', '=', $course["id"]);
    $enroll= Students::where('course_id', '=', $course->id);

    $$result=$course->toArray();
    $enroll= Students::where('course_id', '=', $course["id"]);
```

I need to search the variable where the return value of eloquent query is stored.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: The quesiton is difficult to understand... but you should do the "search" in the database, only query the relation (and conditions) you actually need...

Answer (score 0):

For a specific user and a specific course you can get the collection of records from student table with the following query:

```
$courceId = 1;
$userId = 1;


$enrolled = Students::where('course_id', $courseId)
  ->where('user_id', $userId)
  ->count() > 0;
```

$enrolled will have true or false value

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent `relationship` to obtain this in a much better way. However you can do this like the following assume your `course name` is `$course_name`:

```
$course = Course::where('name', '=', $course_name)->first();
if($course!=null){
    $enroll= Students::where('course_id', '=', $course->id)->get();
}
```

and then you can `check` if it has data or not like

```
if($enroll!=[]){
    echo 'this course has been taken by some student';
  }
```

Here some student are the **$enroll** student.